# How to get 10 latest records from database

Tags: php, mysql

How to display 10 latest jobs from database like this. [Please click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm3vO.png)

I have written following code so far not sure what to do next.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM jobs ORDER BY posting_date DESC LIMIT 10";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) ) {


  $job_title = row["job_title"];
  $company_name = $row["company_name"];
  $department = $row["department"];
  $location = $row["location"];   
  $job_type = $row["job_type"];   
  $job_description = $row["job_description"];
  $posting_date = date('d-m-y');

}
```

The $row returns all the columns from database. I want only four job title, company name, location and date

Comment: SELECT  job_title,company_name,location,posting_date FROM jobs ORDER BY posting_date DESC LIMIT 10

Comment: why do you set `$posting_date `  with today date but not take from the $row?

Comment: Hello thnx for your reply. This is displaying job_title,company_name,location,posting_date for 1 job how to display information for 10 jobs ??

Comment: Anyone notice that `$posting_date = date('d-m-y');` makes no sense? Should probably be: `$posting_date = date('d-m-y', strtotime($row['posting_date']));`

Comment: If you only want the database to select those fields, add them to the SELECT part of your query. If you don't care about the database, but just want the php to select those field, don't assign them in your php code. Otherwise, your question is unclear and should be more specific... :(

Comment: noted thnx i will change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use column names in select query.

```
$query = "SELECT job_title,company_name,location,posting_date FROM jobs ORDER BY posting_date DESC LIMIT 10";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr> <th>Job Title</th> <th>Company Name</th> <th>Location</th> <th>Date Posted</th> </tr>";
echo "<tbody>";  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
  $job_title = $row["job_title"];
  $company_name = $row["company_name"];
  $department = $row["department"];
  $location = $row["location"];   
  $posting_date = date('d-m-y', strtotime($row['posting_date']));

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$job_title."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$company_name."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$location."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$posting_date."</td>";
  echo "<tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Hello Ruchish Parikh thnx for your reply. This is displaying job_title,company_name,location,posting_date for 1 job how to display information for 10 jobs ??    <tr>
        <th >Job Title</th>
        <th >Company Name</th>
         <th >Location</th>
        <th >Date Posted</th>
      </tr>
  
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo "$job_title"; ?></td>       
        <td><?php echo "$company_name"; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo "$location"; ?></td>       
        <td><?php echo "$posting_date"; ?></td>
      </tr><br>
    </tbody>
  </table>

Comment: it will display all 10 jobs just try to echo in while loop. @Rockstar

Comment: check edited code with table structure. It will give you all 10 records in table. :) @Rockstar

Comment: Thank you so much ! Ruchish Parikh it is displaying all jobs now.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm change the query

```
$query = "SELECT job_title, company_name, location,  posting_date FROM jobs ORDER BY posting_date DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order by for rownum

```
$query = "SELECT job_title, company_name, location,  posting_date FROM jobs ORDER BY rownum DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to build a htrml table with the 4 columns:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM jobs ORDER BY posting_date DESC LIMIT 10";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>$row['job_title']</td>";
  echo "<td>$row['company_name']</td>";
  echo "<td>$row['location']</td>";
  echo "<td>$row['posting_date']</td>";
  echo "<tr>";
}
echo "<table>";
```